# Array Cannot Be Resolved To a Variable - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an employee class:

```
public abstract class Employee {

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int joinYear, joinMonth, joinDay;
LocalDate startDate;
static int idCounter=0;
private double employeeId;
private double numEmployees;
Employee[] employeeArray = new Employee[10];
private double monthlyEarnings;
// constructor
public Employee(String first, String last, int year, int month, int day) {
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    joinYear=year;
    joinMonth=month;
    joinDay=day;
    startDate= new LocalDate(joinYear, joinMonth, joinDay);
    this.monthlyEarnings=0;
    this.setEmployeeId(idCounter);
    employeeArray[idCounter]=this;
    idCounter++;
    numEmployees++;
}
}
```

As you can see above, in the constructor, when an employee object is created, it is added to employeeArray: `employeeArray[idCounter]=this;`

Then when I try to access members of the array in my main method I get the error "employeeArray Cannot Be Resolved To a Variable"

```
public class Test {

// test Employee hierarchy
public static void main(String args[]) {
Employee Employee1 = new Employee("John", "Smith", 1997, 8, 20);
Employee Employee2 = new Employee("Bob", "Oak", 1999, 6, 20);


System.out.println(employeeArray[1]); //error here
}
}
```

Comment: You need an instance of that `Employee` class in your class `Test`. Or you can write `Employee1.employeeArray[1]`

Comment: You can not create an instance of an abstract class. Your `Employee` class must be subclassed (or remove the abstract modifier)

Comment: I omitted the code to keep the question to keep it simple, but employee is a superclass. I just want one employeeArray. So would I be correct in saying I should create a new static class for this array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly `employeeArray` is out of the main scope. You need to reference it using `(instance of Employee).employeeArray`.

However, this is quite irrelevant in your case since the logic of your class Employee is broken. The problem is that your `idCounter` and `employeeArray` variables are not shared for all instances of `Employee`. Instead each instance of Employee has its own list and counter (which you seemingly don't want).

As a matter of fact, you need to create a **static** array of `Employee`s within the class itself. It seems to me more appropriate to use a `List<Employee>` instead of an `Employee[]` since you (probably) don't know in advance how many employees you will need to store.

Here is what you should design your class around

```
public class Employee {
    private static List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    // Your instance fields here
    int employeeId;


    public Employee() {
        // Constructor stuff
        this.employeeId = employees.size();

        employees.add(this); // Add the new employee to the list
    }

    public static List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }
}
```

Comment: I only want 1 employeeArray which contains references to each employee object. How do I create this array I presume it needs to be in a static context?

Comment: @DanielRegan you do it not in your employee class. you do it in your main class/method

Comment: How then can I reference it from the Employee class constructor?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid for the purpose of this it has to be an array and not an ArrayList

Comment: Then on the return function addict .toArray()

Answer (score 0):

This error is true:

> employeeArray Cannot Be Resolved To a Variable

You do not have `employeeArray` defined in your test.

You have to get an instance of it from your `Employee` class.

Example:

`System.out.println(Employee1.employeeArray[1]);`